# How to change the type of a constructor parameter through dependency injection

Tags: magento2.2, dependency-injection

We are facing the following situation:
We use a module that is not longer maintained by the developers, but we still would like to use this module. The problem is, the code is not compatible with Magento 2.2.2. In detail, the type of aconstructor's parameter of a Magento_Framework's abstract class has changed. One of the objects in this module inherits from this abstract class and calls the old constructor. Thus, the `setup:di:compile` command crashes.
Our preferred solution is to create a custom module and change the type of the constructor parameter through dependency injection. So, we do not have to change the code of the not-longer maintained module.

This is the error:

```
Compilation was started.
Interception cache generation... 6/7 [========================>---]  85% 32 secs 308.0 MiBErrors during compilation:  
  Vendor\ModuleThatIsNotLongerMaintained\Model\ResourceModel\Collection
        Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface. Actual type: \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb; File: 

Total Errors Count: 1


  [Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception]  
  Error during compilation
```

This is the constructor of the `Vendor\ModuleThatIsNotLongerMaintained\Model\ResourceModel\Collection`:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
    \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    $connection = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
) {
    parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;

    if ($storeViewId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()) {
        $this->_storeViewId = $storeViewId;
    }
}
```

And this is the constructor of the parent class (`Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection`):

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
    \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
) {
    $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
    parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $connection);
    $this->_construct();
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    $this->setConnection($this->getResource()->getConnection());
    $this->_initSelect();
}
```

We were able to solve this error by directly changing the type of the parameter `connection` in the `Vendor\ModuleThatIsNotLongerMaintained\Model\ResourceModel\Collection` to `\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface`, but this is not the solution we aim at.

If we correctly understand the [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html), it should be possible to change the type of constructor parameters through dependency injection.

This is the excerpt of the di.xml of our custom module:

```
...
<type name="Vendor\ModuleThatIsNotLongerMaintained\Model\ResourceModel\Collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="connection" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
...
```

We activated the new custom module and cleaned the caches. But we still get the same error when executing the `setup:di:compile` command.

Did me misunderstood the documentation or did me missed anything?

We appreciate any advice or help!

Comment: can you provide error from DI compilation? code could be useful too

Comment: Thank you for your response @KonradSiamro! We added the error from DI compilation to the question.

Comment: Can you show also constructor for `Vendor\ModuleThatIsNotLongerMaintained\Model\ResourceModel\Collection` ?

Comment: Sorry, that we took so long! Just updated the post.